# PHP array to json with key/index specification

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add a array to a json file using php.

How I want it to look (formatting does not matter):

```
{
    // Already stored in json file
    "swagg_ma_blue":{
        "user":"swagg_ma_blue",
        "admin":true,
        "user_id":"000"
    },
    // Should be added using php
    "dnl":{
        "user":"dnl",
        "admin":"true",
        "user_id":"000"
    }
}
```

How my outcome actually looks like:

```
{"swagg_ma_blue":{"user":"swagg_ma_blue","admin":true,"user_id":"000"},"0":{"user":"d4ne","admin":true,"user_id":"000"}}
```

As you see the array index/key of the second element is called `"0"` but I need it to have the `user` value.

My code:

```
<?php
    class add_mod_class {
        function __construct($username, $status){
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->status = $status;
            $this->user_id = '000';
            $this->json_file = 'includes/json/mods.json';
        }

        function get_json(){
            $json_content = file_get_contents($this->json_file);
            $json = json_decode($json_content, true);
            return $json;
        }

        function mod_handler(){
            if($this->status == 'admin'){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        function add_mod(){
            $mods = $this->get_json();

            $data = array(
                'user' => $this->username,
                'admin' => $this->mod_handler(),
                'user_id' => $this->user_id
            );

            array_push($mods, $data);

            $new_json_string = json_encode($mods);
            return $new_json_string;
        }
    }
?>
```

First idea was to use was:

```
$data[$this->username] = array(
    'user' => $this->username,
    'admin' => $this->mod_handler(),
    'user_id' => $this->user_id
);
```

But this would still return `"0":` in it. I Would appreciate every kind of help.

Comment: Your first idea seems to be the right one, that should do it. Without the `array_push()` of course. How / where are you calling this method and using the results?

Comment: I have to use `array_push()` sadly to re-create the `json_encode`. After this would be done I would save the json code to a file using: `file_put_contents()` and im calling the method in the following format:`if(!empty($_POST)){ require_once('includes/add_mod_class.php'); $mod_user = $_POST['user']; $mod_status = $_POST['status']; $mod_add = new add_mod_class($mod_user, $mod_status); $object = $mod_add->add_mod(); }`

Comment: `array_push` add an element at the end of your array, with a numeric index. Just use `$modes[$this->username] = $data` instead of `array_push($mods, $data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach was fine, except you should assign to `$mods` array instead of `$data`. Here is the corrected function:

```
function add_mod(){
    $mods = $this->get_json();

    $mods[$this->username] = array(
        'user' => $this->username,
        'admin' => $this->mod_handler(),
        'user_id' => $this->user_id
    );

    $new_json_string = json_encode($mods);
    return $new_json_string;
}
```